# How does a function with multiple return statements work?

Tags: c#, return

I am studying for MCSD certification. Given below is the sample code given in my book

```
private bool ValidateRow(TextBox descrTextBox, TextBox quantityTextBox,
        TextBox priceEachTextBox, out int quantity, out decimal priceEach)
{
    // Assume these are 0.
    quantity = 0;
    priceEach = 0;

    // If no values are present, the row is okay.
    if ((descrTextBox.Text == "") &&
        (quantityTextBox.Text == "") &&
        (priceEachTextBox.Text == ""))
        return false;

    // Some values are present to make sure all are.
    if (ValidateRequiredTextBox(descrTextBox, "Description")) return true;
    if (ValidateRequiredTextBox(quantityTextBox, "Quantity")) return true;
    if (ValidateRequiredTextBox(priceEachTextBox, "Price Each")) return true;

    // All values are present.
    // Try to parse quantity.
    if (!int.TryParse(quantityTextBox.Text, out quantity))
    {
        // Complain.
        DisplayErrorMessage(
            "Invalid format. Quantity must be an integer.",
            "Invalid Format", quantityTextBox);
        return true;
    }
```

From the above you can see that there are many return statements. How do these return statements work? As you can see from above "ValidateRequiredTextBox" function is used thrice.

Comment: In case you are banned in Google - [return (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3swy84.aspx)

Comment: What do you mean how do they work? They return the type that the function says it will return. There are multiples because the code can take multiple paths.

Comment: The `ValidateRequiredTextBox` method is called with different parameters. So it will return true or false differently depending on its input parameters. The `return` only happens depending on the results of the `if` statement.

Comment: If you have to ask that, I don't think you're ready for MCSD certification...

Comment: I guess you need to study language basics first :-)

Comment: This is a truly wretched piece of reference code, if it's from an MCSD book. Method has 5 parameters, 2 `out` parameters, uses `false` to mean `valid`, etc.

Comment: @JohnFeminella - I agree.  I've never seen an MCSD exam, but I'm wondering if this is one of those questions where you're supposed to clean up the code so it's "more correct"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return statement exits the method and returns the given value if the return type is other than `void`.
The only statements in the method that are executed after a return statement are the ones in a finally block or the disposal of objects of a using-block (which essentially is a special form of try-finally):

```
private void TestMethod()
{
    // Do something
    if (conditionIsMet)
        return; // Exits the method immediately

    try
    {
        // Do something
        if (conditionIsMet)
            return;  // Statements in finally block will be executed before exiting the method
    }
    finally
    {
        // Do some cleanup
    }

    using (var disposableObj = new DisposableObject())
    {
        // Do something
        if (conditionIsMet)
            return;  // disposableObj will be disposed before exiting the method
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not the only case. `Dispose` method will be called when you `return` from `using` block. You could say that's a special case of `finally`, because that's how `using` is resolved by compiler, but I think it's worth mentioning.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: Yes, you are right - I forgot the using; I'll update the post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

See, return always works once, not multiples. That means whereever return is found the code says compiler to break the flow and go to the end of the method, exception is try-catch-finally where control returns backs to finally block and start executing the code blocks. See sample below:

```
//few codes
string yourname ="jack";
if(yourname="jack")
  return true;
if(yourname="pedro")
  return false;
// more codes
```

Say you are compilling these lines and suppose your name is jack then when it hits the first if statement it will check the condition and since its true so it will return true and will stop the execution of code blocks later to that in that function only.

Answer (score 0):

Your function returning a bool result depending on various conditions. The important thing is if one return statement executes your program won't go to the next line and exits the function.

For example:

```
if (ValidateRequiredTextBox(descrTextBox, "Description")) return true;

if (ValidateRequiredTextBox(quantityTextBox, "Quantity")) return true;
```

Here, if first `ValidateRequiredTextBox(descrTextBox, "Description")` call return true, your function will return true and completed.It won't check other condition.But if `ValidateRequiredTextBox` return false, it will check the other condition and so on.